# Replace URL social media icon

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, social-networking

I'm trying to create share links for social media icons, that will share the current page rather than the specific URL entered in the link. I've managed Twitter and Facebook, but now need Tumblr and Linked In. Is there a JQuery solution that will replace the entered URL with the webpage URL.

```
<a href="http://www.tumblr.com/share/link?url=[get page URL]" class="linked no-ajax">U</a>
```

Does anyone have any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.linked.no-ajax')
.attr('href',
        $('a.linked.no-ajax')
        .attr('href')
        .replace(
                 '[get page URL]',
                 window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
        )
)
```

Comment: please provide more code and check javascript console for us to see the reason